# Powershell - need to parse a text file and past into email

Tags: email, powershell, svn, outlook

I have a very basic text file containing usernames. I need to be able to search for every section that begins with "User bsmith" (for example), copy all the text that follows and end at the line previous to the next "User XXXX" (User tford, for example below).  I will then be pasting the copied text in the body of an email.  I have already written the Powershell to create the email and send it.  I just need to write the portion to grab the text from the text file listed.  Still new to programming, so having a hard time determining what way to search and copy from the .txt file and paste into email body.  The svnlog.txt is the file being parsed.  I can get all content, but need to be able to search for sections for each "User XXXX" to the next "User XXX".

```
$olComObject = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$svn = (Get-Content C:\Dev\Powershell\svnlog.txt) -join "`n"
$NewMail = $olComObject.CreateItem(0)
$NewMail.Subject = "Testing Voting Options"
$NewMail.Body = "Please use the attached voting buttons in this email to acknowledge or reject if the following user permissions are correct!" + "`n" +  $svn
$NewMail.To = "bsmith@company.com;tford@company.com"
$NewMail.VotingOptions = "Accept;Reject"
$NewMail.Send()
```

I was thinking of possibly searching for the individual "User XXX" group using the following, but again I am not sure if this is the right route to go or will even work.

```
$fullsvn = Get-Content "C:\Dev\Powershell\svnlog.txt"
Out-File () "C:\Dev\Powershell\svnlogBSmith.txt"
```

Text file content format is as follows.

User BSmith

repos

[functionalSpecs:/]

@admins = rw

@dba = r

@hca = rw

@businessAnalysts = rw

@qa = rw

@portal = rw

@intercept = rw

@pmo = rw

[restrictedDocs:/softtek]

@restrictedDocs = rw

Groups

BusinessAnalysts = ajones, pjohnson, ssmith, rjackson,

@pmo = lferguson

User tford

Ok.  So I tried TessellatingHeckler's route.  However it doesn't seem to be Tagging the lines with the username (in this instance it's TKelems instead of BSmith).  Here is my current code and an example of the output I get in the console.

```
Get-Content C:\Dev\Powershell\svnlog.txt | foreach {
     if ($_ -match '^User (.*)') {
         $tag = $matches[1]
         }

         [Management.Automation.PSObject]@{
             Tag=$tag
             Item=$_
         }
     }

$TKelems | Where Tag -EQ 'tkelems'

Out-File "C:\Dev\Powershell\svnlogTKelems.txt" -InputObject $TKelems
```

Output:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Tag
Item                           --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tag
Item                           User
Tag
Item                           tkelems:
Tag
Item
Tag
Item                           Repos
Tag
Item                           --------------------
Tag
Item                           [functionalSpecs:/]
Tag
Item                           @admins = rw
Tag
Item                           @eclas = rw
Tag
Item                           @cfis = rw
Tag
Item                           @transMgmt = rw
Tag
Item                           @dba = r
Tag
Item                           @hca = rw
Tag
Item                           @businessAnalysts = rw
Tag
Item                           @qa = rw
Tag
Item                           @portal = rw
Tag
Item                           @intercept = rw
Tag

I also forgot to add the content of the Ou-File created in the last line.  Not sure what to make of this either.  Basically, no tags showing in the console, and the output file shows something totally different (See below):

IsReadOnly     : False

IsFixedSize    : False

IsSynchronized : False

Keys           : {Tag, Item}

Values         : {$null, --------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

SyncRoot       : System.Object

Count          : 2

IsReadOnly     : False

IsFixedSize    : False

IsSynchronized : False

Keys           : {Tag, Item}

Values         : {$null, User}

SyncRoot       : System.Object

Count          : 2

Comment: please past the text file

Comment: You aren't assigning `$TKelems` anywhere in your script... how does it even have any content at all? Make the first line `$TKelems = Get-Content ... | Foreach {` and try it.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  I thought piping it in the last line would take care of that.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: That didn't help. The issue is that I need to define say $TKelems as just the data with the tkelems tag. I would think that defining it in the first line wouldn't work for the rest of the "users" listed in the file. Additionally, I forgot to add the content of the Out-File created. That is added to the post.

Comment: Defining $TKelems at the first line ($TKelems = gc .\log.txt) generates that ouput with all of the values.  As you can see the tag key value is showing as null there, too.  Not sure why this isn't tagging anything.

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
$textfile = 'c:\testfiles\test.txt'

$Search = 'BSmith'

$Found = (Get-Content $textfile -Raw) -split '(?ms)^(?=User)' -like "User $Search*"
```

That will read the text file in as a single string, then split it at the lines starting with "User", and filter out the ones that don't match user name in $Search.

You'll need to add error trapping to check for $found being empty, or returning multiple results and handle to suit.

Comment: I always look forward to seeing your answers. i tend to overthink regular expressions

Comment: Thanks.Multi-line regex can be intimidating at first (mostly because you don't see a lot of examples), but seems to always provide a simpler solution to parsing multi-line text once you get a handle on it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this could be a starting point

```
$usernameregex = 'bsmith'

$found = $false
Get-Content "C:\Dev\Powershell\svnlog.txt" | % {
    if (!$found -and $_ -match "^user $username$") {
        $found = $true
        Write-Output ''
        Write-Output $_
    } elseif ($found -and $_ -match '^user ') {
        if (!($_ -match "^user $username$")) {
            $found = $false
        } elseif ($_ -match "^user $username$") {
            Write-Output ''
            Write-Output $_
        } else {
            Write-Output ''
        }
    } elseif ($found) {
        Write-Output $_
    }
} | select -skip 1 | Set-Content "C:\Dev\Powershell\svnlogBSmith.txt"
```

to check multiple names, change the $usernameregex to this

```
$usernameregex = (bsmith|tford)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this "*I want lines in a file from [section header] to the next [section header]*" before, and mjolinor's answer with the multiline regex is short and effective, but I don't think it's very clear what it's doing and why. And it won't work as nicely on a general array of strings without `-join`ing them first.

As an alternative I quite like the concept of tagging each line, then you can group or filter by the tag. e.g. pull out the username and tag each line with the last-seen username:

```
gc .\log.txt | foreach { 
    if ($_ -match '^User (.*)') {
        $tag = $matches[1]
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Tag=$tag
        Item=$_
    }
}
```

What it does with your file is this:

```
Tag                    Item                                                     
----                   ----                                                     
BSmith                 User BSmith                                              
BSmith                 repos                                                    
BSmith                 [functionalSpecs:/]                                      
BSmith                 @admins = rw                                             
BSmith                 @dba = r                                                 
BSmith                 @hca = rw                                                
BSmith                 @businessAnalysts = rw                                   
BSmith                 @qa = rw                                                 
BSmith                 @portal = rw                                             
BSmith                 @intercept = rw                                          
BSmith                 @pmo = rw                                                
BSmith                 [restrictedDocs:/softtek]                                
BSmith                 @restrictedDocs = rw                                     
BSmith                 Groups                                                   
BSmith                 BusinessAnalysts = ajones, pjohnson, ssmith, rjackson,   
BSmith                 @pmo = lferguson                                         
tford                  User tford                                               
tford
```

Then you can easily:

```
$that | Where Tag -eq 'BSmith'
```

or

```
$that | group Tag
```

It could tag lines with any regex match for section delimiters.

[Edit: Added `^` to the regex, suggested by @mjolinor ]

Comment: This solution will work too, but it may not scale very well if you're dealing with a large number of lines.  I'd advise including the beginning of line anchor (^) in that regex. As it stands, it's got a high potential for unintended consequences. The string 'user' could easlily appear in the arbitrary data following the section header and then you're going to get unexpected results. IMHO.

Comment: @mjolinor I agree with both points (but would GC -Raw scale for lots of lines either? This doesn't need to read them all before it can start working) and the beginning-of-line anchor would make it more robust. I think a general solution for this kind of "*extract lines from X to Y*" question might be a reasonable addition to Select-String, so I've suggested it at the PowerShell uservoice: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/14951235-add-parameters-to-select-string-for-matching-all-l

Comment: Either one will start to suffer from memory exhaustion given a large enough input file, but converting each line to a PS object will do it much faster. I extrapolated the posted data to 5000 users and ran it through both solutions. It took about 12mb of memory to split it into multi-line strings. Rendering each line as a PS object took almost half a gig.

Comment: Ok.  So I have tried TessellatingHeckler's route.  However it doesn't seems to be applying the Tag to the Item.  The ouput lists the items, but shows the Tag as blank.  Here is the output I get in the console.